# Upload to youtube via google api v3 (php) with refresh and access token

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-oauth

I wish to develop one restful app where users will upload video to youtube via some admin interface. Since users will only upload on behalf of my name and in one channel I want to make authentication only once and then use refresh token to get access token.

So what I did is the following

1. I have visited https://developers.google.com and select and authorize all Youtube data API v3 API's with my email
2. Exchange authorization code for tokens (so now I have Authorization code, refresh and access token)
3. Code implementation (stuck here, can't imagine huh?)

```
$client = new Google_Client();

$client->setApplicationName('myApp');
$client->setClientId('<client-id>');
$client->setClientSecret('<client-secret>');
$client->setDeveloperKey('<dev-key>'); // <- do I really need that
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner-channel-audit https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly');
$client->refreshToken('<my-refresh-token>');
$client->setAuthConfig('client_secrets.json'); // <- is that the same as setting clientId and ClientSecret???
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setApprovalPrompt('force');

$accessToken = $client->getAccessToken();
if (is_null($accessToken) || $client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    // How to refresh token with REFRESH token?
    dd($_GET);
}


// Define service object for making API requests.
$service = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

// Define the $video object, which will be uploaded as the request body.
$video = new Google_Service_YouTube_Video();

// Add 'snippet' object to the $video object.
$videoSnippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoSnippet();
$videoSnippet->setCategoryId('1');
$videoSnippet->setChannelId('<my-channel-id>');
$videoSnippet->setDescription('Description of uploaded video.');
$videoSnippet->setTags(['tag', 'tag2', 'tag3']);
$videoSnippet->setTitle('Test video upload.');
$video->setSnippet($videoSnippet);

// Add 'status' object to the $video object.
$videoStatus = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoStatus();
$videoStatus->setEmbeddable(true);
$videoStatus->setLicense('youtube');
$videoStatus->setPrivacyStatus('private');
$video->setStatus($videoStatus);

$queryParams = [
    'stabilize' => false
];

// TODO: For this request to work, you must replace "YOUR_FILE"
//       with a pointer to the actual file you are uploading.
//       The maximum file size for this operation is 64GB.
$response = $service->videos->insert(
    'snippet,status',
    $video,
    $queryParams,
    array(
        'data' => file_get_contents($fullFilePath),
        'mimeType' => 'video/*',
        'uploadType' => 'multipart'
    )
);
print_r($response);
```

So now I have several problems, which I don't know how to tackle.

1. Which `$client->....` functions must be present if I'm already authorized (via OAuth playground)
2. How to refresh token with refresh token?

So far the only response I get is Google_Service_Exception

```
Message: { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "required", "message": "Login Required", "locationType": "header", "location": "Authorization" } ], "code": 401, "message": "Login Required" } }
```

It's my second day of trying to upload video via api with PHP and it's driving me nuts. I hope you guys will help me out.

If you need any additional informations, please let me know and I will provide. Thank you!!

**UPDATE**

After adding following code

```
$client->setAccessToken('<ACCESS_TOKEN>');
```

I get following errors

```
div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>An uncaught Exception was encountered</h4>

<p>Type: Google_Service_Exception</p>
<p>Message: {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtube.quota",
    "reason": "quotaExceeded",
    "message": "The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your \u003ca href=\"/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota\"\u003equota\u003c/a\u003e."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your \u003ca href=\"/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota\"\u003equota\u003c/a\u003e."
 }
}
</p>
<p>Filename: /home/vagrant/workspace/spot-scouting-adminpage/rest/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 118</p>
```

Which is of course not true, since I have never made a single successful request to google. Here is prof:
[image]

Maybe the problem is that a have generated access key via developers.google.com???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed just a small step to set access token.
Once you get the access token set it with google client :

```php
$client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
```

And then use youtube service:

```php
$service = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);
```

Comment: That's true, but access token changes on 3600 seconds. How do you refresh it with refresh token?

Comment: Mentioned code is perfectly fine. Whenever this code executes this will fetch a new access token from refresh token.

Comment: If I add access key, then I have a problem with quotas. Check my updated question

Comment: Quota comes at your application account level and refresh token is generated application specific. So for quota restrictions you either need different applications and refresh tokens or increase the quota with membership.